# DNN with 2sxc throwing 500 error when using WebAPI

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I've attempted first to make my own WebAPI module but was getting back constant 500 errors with a message:

```
Message: An error has occured
Detail: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'CareerRequestController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

After eventually giving up, i downloaded the demo from 2sxc (https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/tutorial-webapi-basic-app-for-dnn-dotnetnuke)

After installing and trying the links I was met with the same error (except SimpleDemoRequestsController instead of CareerRequestController.

Just wondering whats gone wrong if the demo app wont work.

Full Error:

```
"{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'SimpleDemoRequestsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerActivatorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator.Create>b__0()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerActivatorTracer.System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerDescriptorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateController>b__0()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerDescriptorTracer.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unable to resolve SimpleDemoRequestsController.\r\nWhere no service registrations found\r\n  and number of Rules.FallbackContainers: 1\r\n  and number of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers: 0","ExceptionType":"DnnSharp.DryIoc.ContainerException","StackTrace":"   at DnnSharp.DryIoc.Throw.It(Int32 error, Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2, Object arg3)\r\n   at DnnSharp.DryIoc.Container.ThrowUnableToResolve(Request request)\r\n   at DnnSharp.DryIoc.Container.DnnSharp.DryIoc.IContainer.ResolveFactory(Request request)\r\n   at DnnSharp.DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheDefaultDelegate(Type serviceType, Boolean ifUnresolvedReturnDefault)\r\n   at DnnSharp.DryIoc.Container.DnnSharp.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type serviceType, Boolean ifUnresolvedReturnDefault)\r\n   at DnnSharp.DryIoc.WebApi.DryIocDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"}}"
```

Other notes:

2sxc Version: 9.33.0

DotNetNuke Version: 9.2.2

I've reinstalled the 2sxc app twice, the first time was a removal before i upgraded it, then a removal after this 500 error was getting too much.

Comment: Not that this is an answer, or much help - But I've run into many issues when attempting the same thing with 2sxc. It seems to fluctuate from version to version.

Comment: The full error what actually happens can be found in the dnn events. There you should see a full .net error - typically you misspelled a variable name, forgot a closing } or something.

Comment: @iJungleBoy I checked the dnn events first. Weirdly its only if i do actually miss a } or variable that an error shows there, the one i've posted above doesnt show up in dnn events at all only in the console. But i dont see how that would be an issue anyway with a fresh install of 2sxc and a fresh install of the webapi demo (no changes, just straight link click for show current date shows the same error). At the moment im thinking its a dll issue when it was installed

Comment: it could be that the demo is a bit older, maybe some internals have changed and we forgot to check. One of the newer, albeit more complex, examples is the Mobius App which also has webapi.

Comment: ...but I think the demo is ok, unless you made changes, because the online demo https://2sxc.org/dnn-app-demos/en/Apps/Tutorial-WebApi-Basic seems to work without a problem.

Comment: @iJungleBoy Yeah have tested it on a fresh portal and it works, However when i add 2sxc, then remove 2sxc (without clicking the remove files button...i forgot the first time) then add it again it does the same errors. The other thing i found was some packages if they arent right clicked and unblocked first don't install correctly. The only fix i found was to dump the site, spin up a new one and reload the data with a fresh install which was fine for one of my smaller sites. The only issue now is the massive site that it doesnt want to work for.

Comment: @Rando this sounds strange, but at least sound reproducible. I'm not sure what traces 2sxc leaves, but basically you can always "clean-up" an install with removing all the DLLs and the DesktopModules/Tosic_... folder.

Comment: Also note that your app-files are not touched on an un-install. so if you had a blog-app installed in portal 7, then /Portals/7/2sxc/Blog and /Portals/7/Adam/Blog will remain. in rare cases this causes some surprises when re-installing. So if this is the case, just delete these if you want to re-install one of the apps.